# Android: How to pause the launch of next activity if user navigates away from current activity?

Tags: android, splash-screen

I have created a splash screen for my application. After 5 seconds it starts the next activity using the below code. Now my problem is, if user navigates away from current activity before 5 seconds are over, then as soon as 5 seconds are over the next activity (in my case InfoActivity) comes in front even if I am in another application or anywhere else.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.launch);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(LaunchActivity.this, InfoActivity.class);
            LaunchActivity.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
            LaunchActivity.this.finish();
        }
    }, 5000);
}
```

Comment: Handle lifecycle of that activity properly. That should do the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This procedure worked for me.

> flag = false;

```
runnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

        if(!flag) {
            final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(LaunchActivity.this, InfoActivity.class);
            LaunchActivity.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
            LaunchActivity.this.finish();
            }
        }
    };
handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(runnable, 5000);

onPause() {
super.onPause();
flag = true;
handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
}

onRestart() {
super.onRestart();
flag = false;
handler.postDelayed(runnable, timeOfPause-timeOfCreate);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use a variable

```
shouldNavigate=true;
```

that you unset in the onDestroy() method of your original activity.

```
onDestroy() {
    shouldNavigate=false;
    [...]
}
```

In your postDelayed-run()-method you then check

```
if(shouldNavigate) {...}
```